# CString to void*

Tags: c++, windows, type-conversion, void-pointers, cstring

Is it possible to convert `CString` to `void*`. I made a void pointer and pointed it to some object. Now I saved this in a `CString`. Now I want to convert back to `void*` from `CString`.

```
void* pPointer = &SomeObject;
CString myString;
myString.Format(_T("%x"), pPointer);

//void* anotherPointer = (void*)myString;
```

Comment: you saved the address of the void pointer as string in myString and did not cast the pointer to CString, so there is no cast back.

Comment: @mgr if you are talking about %d then it was a typing mistake, i used %x, should i use something else,

Comment: @Faisal Hafeez i just do not understand why you want to store the address of the pointer in the string. if pPointer is a CString* you can do CString* myString = (CString*)pPointer, but this will fail if pPointer is something else.

Comment: It seems to me he wants to store some pointer into a string (as an hex integer), and then parse it back and use it later in code.

Comment: i want to save address of SomeObject and saving it in a string, and some later time i want that address back from the string.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez: I wrote some code that seems to do the job; it seems to work, but more testing is required.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible.

What you can do is to convert `CString*` to `void*` :

```
void* anotherPointer = (void*) & myString;
```

and back :

```
CString* pToMyString = (CString*) anotherPointer;
```

Comment: I'd use **C++ style casts**. Moreover, the first cast (from `CString*` to `void*`) is useless, so I'd just write: `void* anotherPointer = &myString;`. For the second cast, I'd use a `static_cast<CString*>`: `CString* pToMyString = static_cast<CString*>(anotherPointer);`.

Comment: @Mr.C64 I wouldn't cast to `void*` in the first place, but that is a different story.

Answer (score 2):

You can't *"convert"* a `CString` to a `void*`, but you can *"convert"* a `CString*` (i.e. a **pointer** to a `CString`) to a `void*`:

```
// Create a CString object
CString str(_T("Foo"));

// Store CString address in a void* pointer
void* ptr = &str;

// Cast from void* back to CString*
CString* pstr = static_cast<CString*>(ptr);

// Print CString content
_tprintf(_T("%s\n"), pstr->GetString());
```

However, you seem to be doing something different: i.e. storing the address (pointer) of some object as an *integer formatted string* into a `CString`. Then you need to get the integer value back from string, using some parsing function like `_tcstoul()`.
This seems to work, but more testing is required:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atldef.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace ATL;


// Some test class
struct MyClass
{
    string Foo;
    int Bar; 

    MyClass(const string& foo, int bar)
       : Foo(foo), Bar(bar)
    {}
};


// Test
int main()
{
    // Create some object
    MyClass c("A foo", 10);

    // Get the address of the object
    void* ptr = &c;

    // Format the address into a string
    CString str;
    str.Format(_T("%p"), ptr);

    // Parse the address from string
    void* ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<void*>( _tcstoul( str.GetString(), nullptr, 16 ) );

    // Get back the original MyClass pointer
    MyClass* pMyClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(ptr2);

    // Check result
    cout << pMyClass->Foo << endl;
    cout << pMyClass->Bar << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're formatting the string seems wrong. **%d** is for integers, so it will result in the **void*** address being formatted as a number. If that's really what you intended you can parse the string to obtain the number that it contains and then cast it to a **void***. But I'm pretty sure that's not what you intended.

Comment: there was typing mistake, actually i wrote %x, is it correct to use %x for void*, what should i use,

Comment: Yes, %x is just like %d except that the number is formatted in hexadecimal form. But I still don't know what is it you're really trying to do.

Comment: i want to save address of SomeObject and saving it in a string, and some later time i want that address back from the string

Comment: OK, then Mr.C64's answer shows you how to do that. But it still seems weird. Maybe what you're really trying to do is serialization? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bz744w8(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to use the contents of the CString (i.e. write to a file), you need to use the GetBuffer function to get access to the actual contents.

```
void* p = (void*)myString.GetBuffer(1);
...
myString.ReleaseBuffer();
```